# Merging JavaScript files together on the fly in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, javascript

Is it possible to merge several JavaScript files being used on a site into one? I'm looking to do this to minimize server loads by forcing only one download. This way I can keep my JavaScript organized into separate files and still have efficiency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either need to have a batch process merge release scripts from your debug files (YUI compressor is a good tool and there is an API in .NET available on codeplex.com).  Or, you can do what companies like Telerik do, create your own HTTP handler or module that's responsible for merging the files yourself, not an easy task to do.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [ASP.NET tool for doing this](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/HOW%20TO%20Combine%20Scripts%20using%20the%20Script%20Loader.ashx). Don't know if it's any good. There's also [this blog pos](http://msmvps.com/blogs/omar/archive/2008/05/10/fast-asp-net-web-page-loading-by-downloading-multiple-javascripts-in-batch.aspx)t by Omar of PageFlakes fame.

You'd also want to make sure that the combined sripts are minified as well with a tool like YuiCompress or the [tool in the video Oded mentions](http://www.asp.net/learn/3.5-SP1/video-296.aspx?wwwaspnetrdirset=1)